# Running PHP with CURL to copying file to shared folder gives permission denied error

Tags: php, windows, permissions, curl, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Windows on my servers.

I have to periodicly download some file to SERVER1 from FTP server. And then copy those files to shared folder on SERVER2 after downloading them.

For this job, I write a PHP script and I scheduled it with CURL within .BAT file like:

**c:\curl\curl.exe http://localhost/getmyfiles.php**

My script downloads files from FTP correctly. But, when I try to copy downloaded files to SERVER2's shared folder it gives error.

I tryed PHP's **copy** function and PHP's **exec** function, but I coudn't do it.

PHP's copy function gives this error:
**function.copy : failed to open stream: Permission denied**

If I change shared folder's permissions to EVERYONE on SERVER2 it works correctl.

I'm running my scheduled job with ABC user which is can write permission on shared folder.

If I login to SERVER1 with ABC user, I can copy files to shared folder with windows explorer successfuly.

Help please...

Comment: please elaborate on the setup , are u using a mapped drive? is this a domain controller setup? which web server are u using and os as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is probably running as another user than 'ABC'. You should figure out which account PHP uses ([here, perhaps?](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true)) and then allow that user to access the shared folder.